# How to live stream video in facebook with live reading of like counts from facebook?

Tags: video, streaming

I want to stream a video in facebook with graphs that read the likes/reactions from the post and update live in the video itself.

Example : https://www.facebook.com/sportnews07/videos/712585572223590/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple tutorial to capture and stream in real-time Facebook Live reactions: https://socialwall.me/en/capture-stream-in-real-time-facebook-live-reactions/

Comment: Thats not free I guess. You are using a third party app for this. How can we make it using facebook SDK ? Is it an app or what? Please help

Comment: Here is a PHP library to implement this kind of thing: https://github.com/JamesTheHacker/Facebook-Live-Reactions

Answer (score 0):

You can directly make such live videos using my site, [Shuriken Live](https://www.shurikenlive.com).

The whole process is quite complicated as it needs to hit Facebook graph API after every few seconds to update the video and also you need to encode and stream the video to RTMP server of Facebook.

I have achieved this task by screen capturing the browser which opens a html page. In that HTML page, I have written the JS code to hit Facebook API and update the count of reactions in the HTML.
So, screen capture automatically grabs all the updates and send it to RTMP server.

I hope you will like my work.